# Append StackPanel to Grid in Window C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm attempting to add a StackPanel to a Grid on this Window, I have passed the Window to the method.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Show single notifications
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="window"></param>
        public static void showSingle(Window window)
        {
            // Find the resource, then cast it to a runtimeObject
            var runtime = (runtimeObject)Application.Current.TryFindResource("runtimeVariables");
            Style style = Application.Current.Resources["NotificationsContainer"] as Style;

            //Create container control
            StackPanel container = new StackPanel();
            container.Style = style;

            //Append to Window
            window.Container.Children.Add(container);
        }
```

This is the XAML of the Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Test_Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_Project"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:Extensions="clr-namespace:Test_Project.Classes"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Controls;assembly=Controls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="609.925" Width="573" Name="Main">
    <Grid Name="Container">
```

I'm getting an error however saying:

> 'Window' does not contain a definition for 'Container' and no
>   extension method 'Container' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I have got a feeling i'm doing this wrong, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

public static void showSingle(Window window) - Window is a base class and it doesn't contain definition for Container. You should use your Window class (MainWindow).

Comment: I pass the MainWindow instance to showSingle() method though.

Comment: but inside function it will be casted to Window. And you will have your error.

Comment: What is another way to do this then? I don't want code-behind in my Views

Comment: In your code snippet:
if(window is MainWindow)
{
 ((MainWindow)window).Container.Children.Add(container);
}

Comment: I want this method to be universal, so it might not be MainWindow, it should be Window2 for example

Comment: @OG. So really I need to search any referenced Window for the Grid name

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, that is what I was after.